# Copying values from text file to a list

Tags: python, list, append, file-handling

When I copy some values from text file to a list a "\n" is also being printed. How can I remove that. I tried split(), replace(), remove() and so many ways but didn't work.

I am expecting to remove the "\n" when values are copied from text file to list

Comment: just describe your problem in an appropriate manner and give some samples. and show your progress code.

Comment: How about showing us some of those ways you're talking about.  Please also provide some sample input.  Without more to go on, all you're going to get here is a pointer to one of the probably hundreds of tutorials and examples on how to read from a file in Python.  If your case is in some way non-trivial, then you need to explain why that is.  How are we supposed to know why what you're trying isn't working when you haven't shown us what it is you're doing?

Comment: Show minimal example of input, output, and code.  Guess would be you're not removing '\n' at end of each line of the file e.g. `line = line.rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, but You need to use `strip()`

Comment: Not true.  They may WANT to use `split()`, but they shouldn't have to The most usual method of iterating over lines in a text file removes the newlines.

Answer (score -1):

Try This!

```
file = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file.readlines()

wordlist = []

for line in Lines:
    word = (line.split()[0])
    wordlist.append(word)
```

Comment: A'm I just missing it?  I don't see the specification that only the first word on each line should be saved to the accumulating list.